# Puppet + Apache + SSL

Tags: ssl, puppet, certificate

I am fairly new with puppet but not new to the server administration world.

I've managed to get a puppet master up and running as well as a puppet node on a different machine. I've been working on configuring the node as a web server. I've configured my first non SSL vhost and all seems well.

I've went to setup a SSL Vhost but this is where I am running in to what I suspect is a trivial problem. I have the SSL Key/Cert/CSR/Intermediate Chain file. However, after googling I cannot seem to be able to get these files copied over to the node, automatically, through puppet.

Any help would be welcomed!

Comment: Need more information.  I suspect you're using some apache puppet module downloaded from somewhere but not specifying which.

Answer (score 0):

You want to organize your site manifest into modules. These allow you to [store files](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/modules_fundamentals.html#files) in canonical locations so that you can deploy them to agents using the [file type](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#file-attribute-source), e.g.

```
file { "/etc/apache2/ssl/chain-and-key.pem":
  ensure => file,
  source => "puppet:///mymodule/etc/apache2/ssl/chain-and-key.pem";
}
```